# websocketpp | Can't set on_close/ open handler

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket

when I try to set the set_close_handler, I'm getting this exception:

```
rm -rf build/*.o main command_prompt
rm -rf *.o main command_prompt
g++ -o build//main.o -std=c++11 -DRASPBERRY_PI -DBCM2835_NO_DELAY_COMPATIBILITY -D__BASEFILE__=\"build/main\" -c -Ilibs/lmic/src -Ilibs/  main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘void on_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl)’:
main.cpp:75:3: error: ‘m_connections’ was not declared in this scope
   m_connections.erase(hdl);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:226:70: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       echo_server.set_close_handler(bind(&on_close,&echo_server,::_1,));
                                                                      ^
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'build/main.o' failed
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 1
rebuild.sh: line 3: ./main: No such file or directory
```

I've already tried playing around with the parameters and the client pointer in the on_close event but that didn't change a thing.
I've successfully set the on message handler, but when I try to set the on open handler it throws the same exception.

```
void on_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl)

}

echo_server.set_close_handler(bind(&on_close,&echo_server,::_1,));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including of this line should fix your problem:

```
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo_server.set_close_handler(bind(&on_close,&echo_server,::_1, ));
                                                               ^
                                            missing an argument here
```

Comment: woops, sry forgot to remove it before posting, that's not the cause for the exception.